# persistence of member variables in an "Activity" class

Tags: android, persistence, android-activity

Why don't the member variables "m_lat" and "m_lng" persist
between the "onCreate" and "onClick" calls, but the Intent
returned from  getIntent() does?

(I think the .xml file is irrelevant)

Code follows:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {

        int m_lat, m_lng;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        m_lat = i.getIntExtra("LAT", -1);
        m_lng = i.getIntExtra("LNG", -2);

                // here, m_lat m_lng have good values

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent oldInt = getIntent();

        int new_lat = oldInt.getIntExtra("LAT", 0);
        int new_lng = oldInt.getIntExtra("LNG", 0);

            // here, m_lat and m_lng are 0, but
            // new_lat and new_lng are now valid

    }

}
```

Tks!

Answer (score 1):

Pls, check Android developer documents.

> public int getIntExtra (String name, int defaultValue)
>
> Since: API Level 1 Retrieve extended data from the intent.
>
> Parameters
>
> name:  The name of the desired item.
>
> defaultValue:  the value to be
>   returned if no value of the desired type is stored with the given
>   name.
>
> Returns
>
> the value of an item that previously added with putExtra() or the
>   default value if none was found.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntExtra(java.lang.String, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntExtra%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Comment: I think you missed my point.  In the "onCreate" method, the class sets two member variables (m_lat, m_lng).  But in the "onClick" method, the values of m_lat and m_lng are lost. I would expect m_lat == new_lat and m_lng == new_lng, but that's not the case. I'd like to know why the member variables don't persist between calls.

Comment: Pls check your code again or rebuild your project. May you change values of m_lat and m_lng at some point in your code. I have no problem with code that you given.